# Как перевести произвольные полян в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wordpress-multisite

Я использую плагин  WP Multilang для мультиязычного сайта.
у него есть core-config.json

Я хочу реализовать перевод произвольных типов полей. Не могу найти куда вписать и что вписать в json чтобы заработал перевод полей.
Например у меня поля:

description
keywords
Seo Text Headline
Seo Text Paragraph

Для разных версия сайта есть разные произвольные поля.

в Джисоне я нашел такую запись:

```
"post_fields": {
    "_wp_attachment_image_alt": {}
  },
```

Но пробовал вписать что то типо этого:

```
  "post_fields": {
    "_wp_attachment_image_alt": {},
    "get_post_meta": {},
    "_wp_get_post_meta": {}
  },
```

Не аолучилось

Вот ссылка на плагин который я использую
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multilang/

Comment: Там прямо на указанной тобой странице  странице написана инструкция. в ней синтаксис. И никакие джосоны трогать ненужно.

Comment: Ну так все правильно там описан джисон, но дело в том что я эти правила вписываю но не работает, если вам не трудно, помогите плиз!

Comment: синтаксис мультистрок смотри .а не джосон.